# Find matrix $M$ such that $AM=0$ and $MA \neq 0$ where $0<\mathrm{rk}(A)<n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to find a matrix $M \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AM=0$ and $MA \neq 0$ where $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is not invertible and not zero.

I thought of taking $a$ and $m$ the canonical endomorphisms related to $A$ and $M$ and build $m$ such that $\mathrm{im}(m) = \ker(a)$ to have $a \circ m =0$ but I need also $\mathrm{im}(a)$ not to be included in $\ker(m)$ otherwise $m\circ a$ would be $0$ too.

This should not be that hard, but I can't see what to do right now.

Comment: What is $n$? Do you require $A$ and $M$ to be square matrices?

Comment: @AnuragA I edited. $n$ is the size of the matrices and yes these are square matrices.

Comment: You're on the right track. Take two basis $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ and $(f_1, \dots, f_n)$ such that $\ker a = \operatorname{span}(e_1, \dots, e_k)$ and $\operatorname{Im} a = \operatorname{span} (f_1, \dots, f_{n-k})$.

Comment: @Astyx Thank you for your hint. I thought of it but I am stuck there, how can I fully define $m$ with these two basis? Could I get another hint please?

Comment: Do you know you can define a linear map fully and uniquely by its values on a basis. In this case, you'll want to define it on the $f_i$'s.

Comment: @Astyx This looks so obvious now, sorry for bothering. I just can complete the basis of $\mathrm{Im}(a)$ to make a basis $(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (I just need a basis with one of the $f_i$) then I can define $m$ by $m(f_i) = e_1$ for all $i$, hence $a \circ m = 0$, moreover there exists $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $f_1 = a(x) $ and $m(a(x)) = e_1 \neq 0$...

Comment: @Astyx Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a nonzero $v\in\operatorname{null}(A)$, and $w\not\in\operatorname{null}(A)$. Complete $\{Aw\}$ to a basis $\{Aw,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ and define
$$
MAw=v,\qquad Mx_j=0,\quad j=2,\ldots,n.
$$
Then $MA\ne0$ by construction. And
$$
A(Mw)=0,\qquad  AMx_j=0,\quad j=2,\ldots,n,
$$
so $AM=0$.